# Website is not loading wordpress site. Showing Index folder instead

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

I recently deleted the `index.html` file to stop the default Apache page from displaying, but now the image above is what I see when trying to access website. My domain name and IP are directing to an index view, rather than my actual WordPress site:

[image: Index]

The `wordpress` directory is inside `/var/www/html`

Do I need to somehow move the WordPress files from the `wordpress` directory into `/var/www/html` for them to be recognised? If so, what command would be used to do this?

Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Looking at the date in the image, you have been using the WordPress site for quite some time. Moving the files up one directory may break things in unexpected ways. Instead, you may want to edit your Apache configuration to use `/var/www/html/wordpress` as the root instead. Note that this may require you to change your website’s domain if you have something like `example.com/wordpress` as the site’s landing.

Comment: The date on the image is incorrect. I've just started the wordpress site and server a couple of days ago.

But how would I edit the apache configuration to use /var/www/html/wordpress using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to edit your Apache configuration file to use `/var/www/html/wordpress` as the new web root, you can do it like this:

0. Open Terminal (or connect to the server via SSH)
1. Change to Apache's `sites-enabled` directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
   ```
2. List the contents of the directory to see what the currently-enabled configuration file is called:

   ```
   ll
   ```

   This will give you something like this:

   ```
   total 8
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  1 06:59 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Mar 19 06:24 ../
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jul 19  2021 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
   ```
3. Edit the configuration file:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} 000-default.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice, be it nano, vim, or anything else that can edit text.</sup>
4. Find the `DocumentRoot` value and edit it accordingly:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
   ```
5. Save the file
6. Restart/Reload the Apache configuration files:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

That's all there is to it